# ListView with continious fill is not virtualizing

Tags: wpf, performance, templates, listview, controls

I changed the control template of my ListView to look like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <ScrollViewer Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                  ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <Border x:Name="FillerView" BorderThickness="0"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </ScrollViewer>
</Border>
```

The reason for this is, that I want the alternating coloration of the `ListView` to continue. This is done via trigger for the `FillerView` Border. If I remove the `Stackpanel` and the border `Fillerview` from this template my `ListView` is virtualizing normally and very fast. If I have it in there it is incredibly slow.

Can anyone tell my why the virtualizing does not work when I use the template above? Oh and I can not move the Border `FillerView` out of the `Scrollviewer` because I want the bottom scrollbar to be below the filler.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, Have you set `ListView.ItemsPanel`  as `VirtualizingStackPanel`?

Comment: As I sayd, the ListView works fine if I remove the StackPanel and the Border around the ItemsPresenter. I additionally added these lines but Virtualisation is still off when I keep the mentioned code around the itemspresenter.         
<Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtualizing doesn't work because virtualization requires that the ItemsPanel of the ItemsPresenter is measured with an actual available size. In your case you have a StackPanel as the Content of the ScrollViewer and that will be the IScrollInfo for the ScrollViewer. Now because StackPanel measures its children with infinity in the direction of the arrangement that means it will measure your ItemsPresenter with an infinite height so it would not be possible for the ItemsPanel (which would be the child of the ItemsPresenter) to know the actual available height so it could not virtualize.

I'm not sure what you mean about the alternating coloration of the listview. If you're talking about alternating background of the items within the listview then normally one would use the [AlternationConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.alternationconverter).

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for your answer. That might actually be it.

What I wanted to do with the border and the stack panel is the continue the coloring of the alternation into the empty area below the listview items. So if 10 Items would fit the screen but only 3 are in the list, I want the alternating coloration to continue to the end of the list view even though there are no items anymore. This coloration is done by the border.

Comment: I just checked if it helps to set the height explicitly for the Scrollviewer or the StackPanel. I also replaced the StackPanel with a DockPanel but nothing works it is still not virtualizing.

Comment: No setting a Height on the ScrollViewer or StackPanel will not help. The StackPanel will still measure its children with an infinite height. Really you cannot do what you want. If the StackPanel is the IScrollInfo then it will scroll each item - which in your case means the ItemsPresenter is one really tall item and the Border is the other - or the ScrollContentPresenter is the IScrollInfo in which case it measures the StackPanel with an infinite height and it does pixel level scrolling of its content (the stackpanel).

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is to write your own panel and have the panel draw in the background where the items don't exist. This would be involved as you would have to implement IScrollInfo and you'd want to make a derived VirtualizingPanel. Maybe you could derive from VirtualizingStackPanel, override the OnRender and enumerate the children to find out where the bottom most one is and draw in the remaining area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation! Maybe I will try to do a workaround with a template selecotr that will only use the template above if there are less then 10 items of so. But again thanks you helped me a lot!